# How to sort data while printing line by line in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I'm writing a shell script traversing a list of directories and counting words from files inside them. The code prints data each time I read a file. So the output is not sorted. How can I sort it?

The output right now is like this:

```
cat 5
door 1
bird 3
dog 1
```

and I want to sort it first by second column and then by first column:

```
dog 1
door 1
bird 3
cat 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I tried to reproduce what OP is doing, so after creating the files, I tried this command:

```
% for i in *; do echo -n "$i "; wc -w < $i; done
bird 3
cat 5
dog 1
door 1
```

Then I have added the sort:

```
 % (for i in *; do echo -n "$i "; wc -w < $i; done) | sort -n -k 2 -k 1    
dog 1
door 1
bird 3
cat 5
```

Comment: Just add `-r`  to the `sort` for reverse sorting.

Comment: when I use -r the door comes before dog. I still want names in ascending order

Comment: @aykutyilmaz Try `sort -k1 | sort -rnsk2`

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your shell script to:

```
sort -n -k2 -k1
```

With `-n` you specify numeric sort and with `-k2` that you want to sort first by the second field and with `-k1` to sort then by first field.

Comment: I added many kind of sort pipe to end of my echo but nothing happens.

Comment: just echo  "$name  $count" . Is that important  printing after each file search ?

Comment: you'll put this command not after each file search but when you are calling your shell script